# wordpress website has 25,000 pages with rel="nofollow" can I delete them all at once?

Tags: wordpress, rel, nofollow

I am looking for a way to mass edit my entire wordpress site. I have 25000 pages with rel="noFollow", and I need to delete that from every page.  I am doubtful, but is there a way to automate this process, or am I stuck removing the "nofollow" tags one at a time?

Comment: Are you talking about changing inside your database or in the filesystem?

Answer (score 1):

An easy solution is to dump your database. Then in a text editor like Sublime Text you can do a search and replace. Then reupload your db.

Answer (score 0):

It will depend in what you want to replace a link in the theme or content in the database.

Before you do any changes to the database, remember to create a backup. Also, consider setting up a development site to perform any test. That way you can test as many plugins as you can without fear of messing up your website.

To do what you want, [Better Search Replace](https://wordpress.org/plugins/better-search-replace/screenshots/) can help you replace text in the database. You just need to use the HTML code you want to replace. In your case rel="nofollow" with a blank field.